# Sierpinski Triangle Applications

Tags: geometry, triangles

Sierpinski triangles seem to be a pretty common fractal. After lots of searching, I can't seem to find where you find this pattern in nature or technology. Are there any examples in nature? What about technology? For technology, these does seem to be something with cellular automata, but is that how you make it, or does it have a roll to play in that?

Anything else interesting about it?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve#Uses_of_the_curve

Comment: [Sierpiński curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpiński_curve) and [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) are distinct things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strict mathematical fractals don't exists in Nature or in reality, because their infiniteness would yield various paradox while the physical world is finite (e.g. at some point you get atoms).
And basic mathematical fractals are too regular for Nature, where fractal-like patterns have more irregular variations.

Still, Pascal triangle with modulo looks quite like Sierpinski triangle, and some cell phone ultra-compact antenna are not without similarities.

Also, systems to amortise energy at all frequencies (sound, water waves) have more or less fractal shape.

NB: I won't say "cellular automata" are a "technology".